# Why I didn't get the answer I expected?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to solve this problem with the r language. But I didn't get the answer I expected. My code return -5, while the correct return should be -5, 0, 0, 0, 5. I think my code didn't go through everything in the input_vector. How can i fix it?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Since you'll be visiting often, in addition to @akrun comment/answers below, learn to love `debug(my_new_function)` or `debugonce(my_new_function)`, the letters `s`, `n`, `c`, and the function`ls()`, that allow you to track intermediate results of a function, for loop, etc, to see if things are going as you expect.  Additionally, in debug, you can experiment with different code at different steps to see if they might serve better than what you have. It will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Also please don't share screenshots - instead, copy and paste the actual code. This makes it more likely for you to find help. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need any loop i.e.

```
lambda <- 4
ifelse(abs(v1) > lambda, v1, 0)
[1] -5  0  0  0  5
```

Or simply multiply by the logical vector (`TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0)

```
v1 * (abs(v1) > lambda)
[1] -5  0  0  0  5
```

---

But, if the intention is to use `for` loop, create a output vector to collect the output and `return` once at the end

```
sign.function <- function(input_vector) {
out <- numeric(length(input_vector))
for(i in seq_along(input_vector)) {
  if(abs(input_vector[i]) > lambda) { 
    out[i] <- input_vector[i]

} 
}
return(out)

}
> sign.function(v1)
[1] -5  0  0  0  5
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(-5, -3, 0, 3, 5)
```